# Bootstrap Grid Positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Bootstrap Grids

I'm having an problem with the Bootstrap grid system can't seam to position my content the right way that I want to. Here is what I have so far.

---

```
 <header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"><img src="logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"/></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><h3>My Website</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

### Goal

What I want to achieve is to have a full width web page for large desktops and responsive for mobiles where the logo image and the "My website" slogan will be on the left and the content will be positioned in the center. 
Here are some images of what i want to achieve on desktop and mobile http://s16.postimg.org/tbt4b5det/Untitled_1.png - Desktop
http://s10.postimg.org/mbijfjvkp/Untitled_2.png - Mobile
check below what  have:

```
 <section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <img src="/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h4>Welcome</h4></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h4>How are you?</h4></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="disclaimer">
          <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <span>Follow Us</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### Other Issues

It seams every time i test for different devices or simple resize the browzer the image goes extra small until it get to sm devices and than again continues to get smaller.

### Thank You

I thank you for your help i'm new in web development any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is by changing the container class to `<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:left;">` allowing for full width usage of a screen.

Then, just put a `<div style="text-align: center;">` around what you want to center.

Though this will make all elements stretch the entire screen width, including the `col-*-*` classes. Just add `col-*-offset-*` as required to adjust for this.

Your img is getting smaller because of the img-responsive class.

Comment: I added some images so you can check them.

Comment: Thanks, I just had a look at them, you still want to use the container-fluid, but as well as this use @media queries regarding mobile centering. You'll want to set them the same as bootstraps, which a quick Google will find. Then at mobile scale, set text-align to center, for the body. At desktop scale, set text-align to initial and add the text-align center to just the content

Comment: I still cant make it workin :./ but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Tbh, scrap bootstrap, just set it to text-align center for the body and at a media query, set the top and bottom bit to text align left, like so `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)`

Comment: Hmm I tied but still the grids look weird. And even tho I removed the responsive image class it still keeps shrinking. How about we chat on skype or some social media, Ill pay you for your time i want to learn this

Comment: @Neo sure, send me your Skype

Comment: I send u an email and followed u on Twitter

Comment: @Neo I sent you an email regarding this

Comment: I can't do the 3rd projects, but I can do the 1st & second